# restore fragment in viewpager FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a ViewPager with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (which has many pages) was causing memory issues.

This works well, however I'd like to be able to restore pages (`ListFragments`) to their original position when the Fragment is recreated. This seems straightforward but I'm not having much luck achieving it.

Does anyone have any tips?

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Fragment fragment = new PostListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Map<String, String> categoryitem=categoryList.get(position);
    args.putString("slug", categoryitem.get("slug"));
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

In PostListFragment I am calling web services to get posts based on "slug".

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
    slug=bundle.getString("slug");

    Log.v("PostList Fragment of"+slug,"onCreateView");

    getPosts(slug);

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_list, container, false);
    progressDialog = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    postRecyclerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerview);
    postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    postRecyclerView.removeAllViews();
    return view;
}
```

Here every time webservice is being called. I want to call webservice just once for specific slug and then store that slug's posts and reuse those posts without calling webservice again.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

HomePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
SlidingTabLayout slidingTabs;
ViewPager viewPager;
MyDb db;
public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    pagerAdapter=new HomePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() ,getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

    slidingTabs=(SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    viewPager=(ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    slidingTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, R.id.title);

    db=new MyDb(getActivity());
    slidingTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {

        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
        }
    });

    slidingTabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}
```

}

My FragmentPagerAdapter Class

```
public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

Context context;
private SharedPreferences mySharedpref;
String userId;
MyDb db;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

ArrayList<Map<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

public HomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context=context;
    this.mFragmentManager = fm;
    mySharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    userId=mySharedpref.getString("userId", "0");
    db=new MyDb(context);
    categoryList = db.getCategoryFromDb("30");
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Fragment fragment = new PostListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Map<String, String> categoryitem=categoryList.get(position);
    args.putString("slug", categoryitem.get("slug"));
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return categoryList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  return super.getPageTitle(position);
    Map<String, String> categoryTitle=categoryList.get(position);
    return categoryTitle.get("title");

    //  return title[position];

}
```

}

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Set `setOffscreenPageLimit(num_of_fragmens);` for your viewpager which will prevent memory issue. Use karyu che aa property code ma?

Comment: I don't want to use ' setOffscreenPageLimit();' as all webservices will be called in one shot. There are like 12 to 13 slugs.

Comment: While you swipe your fragments new instance of fragment will be created everytime

Comment: yes. and only after user swipes or selects that slug. Do you have any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Oh So i think you should create your fragments dynamically depends on your slugs.

Comment: Ok well this is fine; But if `getPosts(slug)` method is pass slug as a parameter then yes it is normal case that everytime web service will be called.

Comment: Here the fragment will be only one but the content of different slugs will be loaded in that fragment.